# why in 0-1 Knapsack problem we use INT_MIN and why the 0 is not working

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, knapsack-problem

why in the 0-1 Knapsack problem INT_min is used in the return statement of (max<0)  i have tried putting 0 in place of INT_MIN but I am getting 65 rather than correct answer 60 why this is happening can please any one explain me here is recursive code of knapsack problem

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int solve(int v[],  int w[] , int n ,int max){
    if (max < 0) {
        return INT_MIN;      // here this is giving me problem if I use 0 in place of 
                            // INT_min I get wrong ansewrs
    }
 
    if (n < 0 || max == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    
    int include = 0 ; 
    int exclude = 0 ;
    include = v[n]+solve(v,w, n-1,max - w[n]); 
    exclude = solve(v,w, n-1,max); 
    
    if(include<exclude){
        return exclude;
    }else{
        return include;
    }
}
int main(){
    int v[] = { 20, 5, 10, 40, 15, 25 };
    int w[] = { 1, 2, 3, 8, 7, 4 };
    int W = 10;
 
    int n = sizeof(v) / sizeof(v[0]);

    cout<< solve(v,w,n-1,W)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

for this array I am getting answer 60 if I am using the INT_MIN in return statment and getting 65 if I use 0 in return statment.

Comment: Note that it would be possible (and in fact better) to write an implementation of knapsack that does return 0 in this case, rather than INT_MIN. The use of INT_MIN is somewhat of a trick here.

Answer (score 2):

Let's imagine we are simulating the recursion procedure manually.

At first, we pick the last object (`v=25, w=4`) and drops the last-second object (`15v, 7w`). Now we have 25 value and 4 weight. Afterward, at the next step `N-3` where N is the number of objects, we are going to determine whether to include the last-third object (`40v, 8w`) or not.

Then here are the two subsequent recursive calls in the current step:

```py
include = 40+solve(v,w, N-4,(10 - 4) - 8);
exclude = solve(v,w, N-4,(10-4));
```

If `INT_MIN` is returned when `max < 0`, `include = 40 + INT_MIN = SOME_EXTREMELY_SMALL_VALUE`. And `exclude = SOME_NON_ZERO_VALUE > include`. It implies that the last-third object cannot be picked as it will overfills the knapsack, considering the current left capacity is just `10-4=6`.

If `0` is returned instead, `include = 40+0=40`. And `exclude = SOME_VALUE < 40`. It implies that the last-third object is actually picked in addition to the last object even though it just overfills the knapsack, resulting in a total weight of `4+8=12>10` and the invalid answer `40+25=65`.

Comment: you answer is to complex to understand can you give it in simple form

Comment: As said by @Stef, `INT_MIN` is just a trick to mark cases where `max > 0` as invalid. If not marking these as invalid, overfilling the knapsack will be treated as a possible solution, which gives the wrong answer.

Comment: Which part do you think is complex?

Comment: @Dummy  how can overfilling become a valid case if i return 0 it should not matter and should get out of that function instance with value 0.

Comment: The `0` is returned to its parental `solve(v, w, N-3, 4)` function in the recursion. Inside `solve(v, w, N-3, 4)`, `solve(v,w, N-4,(10 - 4) - 8)` evaluates to `0`, so `include = 40 + 0 = 40`. The `include` will be compared with `exclude` which is smaller than `include`. So this `include` is picked and the final answer is `include + PREVIOUSLY_CHOSEN_OBJECTS = 40 + 25 = 65`.